# React Redux with Router Location, Pagination / Sorting and Fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux, pagination, redux-saga, query-string

I'm writing some generic Todo-List component, with the following features

- Pagination / Sorting
- Keep a part of the state within the URL (page, sort)
- Fetching the Data asynchronously using HTTP Requests (using redux-saga)

Now I'm trying to find a pattern for the "best" sequence of redux actions to get this working without problems.

**I want the following behavior:**

- When Todo Component loads: Read URL Query Parameters and use this to fetch the data.
- When the user clicks `sort by name` (or `next page` or `filer by xyz`) the Query Parameters within the URL should be updated and the next data should be fetched.

**What my current code does:**

I'm creating the props `todos`, `pagination` and `sort` within react-redux's `mapStateToProps`:

```
state => {
    todos: state.venues.page,
    pagination: parsePagination(state.router.location.search),
    sorting: parseSorting(state.router.location.search)
}
```

Within the component I have lifecycle and methods like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // these props come from redux's "mapStateToProps"
    dipatch(executeFetch(this.props.pagination, this.props.sorting));
}

onSortingChange = (sorting) => {
    // this will use connected-react-router's "push"
    // to update the browser's URL
    dispatch(dispatchSetSortingQueryParam(sorting));
}

onPaginationChange = (pagination) => {
    // same as "onSortingChange"
    dispatch(setPaginationQueryParam(sorting));
}
```

**Now the big questionmark:**

Where / How should I run `executeFetch` when `sorting` or `pagination` changes?

- **componentDidUpdate ?** This looked promising, but: it creates an endless loop, because each `executeFetch` will trigger a component update, which then will run `componentDidUpdate` again and again. I could check here if `pagination` and / or `sorting` has changed, and then run `executeFetch`, **but** I get a new object instance for those two props every time any prop changes, which requires then a deep equality check. Not nice.
- adding `executeFetch` at the end of each `onSortingChange` and `onPaginationChange`. This seems to work, but feels a bit redundant. Another problem is, that I can't use `this.props.sorting` and `this.props.pagination` to run `executeFetch`, because those props will aren't updated yet.

How do you solve this within your applications?

Comment: I think I have a pretty good answer for this. Did you come with anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the scenario you're describing:

[image]

The loop requires that you do equality checking to only update the redux state under certain conditions. This is a problem created by having a component that re-renders from **both** the url state and redux state. Separating that logic into two components should work:

[image]

In practice that might look like:

```
let App = () => (
  <Router>
    <>
      <Route component={class extends Component {
        componentDidUpdate() {
          let { pagination, sorting } = parse(window.location.search)
          dipatch(executeFetch(pagination, sorting));
        }
        render() { return null }
      }} />
      <Route path="/todo_list" component={props => (
        <div>
          {/* change url via link */}
          <Link to={...}>Change Page</Link>
          {/* change url programatically */}
          <input
            onChange={e => props.history.push(...)}
          />
        </div>
      )} />
    </>
  </Router>
)
```

Where the todolist is not dispatching actions to modify the url, but just using `<Link />` components or `history.push` to add the pagination and sorting information.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using `connected-react-router`, though basically URL should be part of redux state. The approach looks interesting. But I guess you're missing the last part: The Component will also update the URL. When the user clicks "next page", the URL has to change. Could you add some more code for this use case?

Comment: Just use links? `<Link />` components?

Comment: Also I think syncing the url state with redux is a bad idea, but that's just me

Comment: `Link`s won't work for all scenarios. For example I have some kind of "live-search". While the user is typing in the search input box, the URL automatically changes (`todos?page=1&searchQuery=test`) and the search executes.